# Win32Exception thrown on icon deserialization on Windows 2000/XP

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

I have a WinForm application, on my form I have used the designer to select an .ico file for my form's Icon property.

This works fine on the Windows 7 machines I use to develop and the engineers work on, but when I attempt to launch the software the older Windows XP or 2000 machines on our workbenches there is an exception thrown.

Here is the exception and stack trace that I logged:

```
GUI[13:25:51:808]:Exception Caught | TargetInvocationException:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
GUI[13:25:51:808]:Exception stack trace:
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._SerializationInvoke(Object target, SignatureStruct& declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(Object target, SignatureStruct declaringTypeSig, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.SerializationInvoke(Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.DeserializeObject(Int32 typeIndex)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObject(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
   at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean isString)
   at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet.GetObject(String key, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name)
   at Bench_Test_Software.BenchTestForm2.InitializeComponent()
   at Bench_Test_Software.BenchTestForm2..ctor()
   at Bench_Test_Software.Program.Main()
GUI[13:25:51:808]:Inner Exception:
GUI[13:25:51:808]:Exception Caught | Win32Exception:
The parameter is incorrect
GUI[13:25:51:808]:Exception stack trace:
   at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height)
   at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
```

Why could this be happening?

Comment: Is the appropriate .net framework installed there?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Yes, the program worked perfectly until I updated with shiny new icons to replace the default ones.